# How to insert an array into database

Tags: php

```
$rate=[10,20,40,50,70];
```

How do I insert the value in below query?

```
$sql="INSERT INTO rental(day_1,day_3,day_7,day_15,day_30)
      VALUES('{$rate[0]}','{$rate[1]}', '{$rate[2]}','{$rate[3]}','{$rate[4]}')";

$stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

I tried below but it inserts same value in all column for a record and creates new record for each new value:

```
foreach($rate as $key->$value)
{  
    $sql="INSERT INTO rental(day_1,day_3,day_7,day_15,day_30)
          VALUES('{$value}','{$value}', '{$value}','{$value}','{$value}')";

    $stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Edited based on answer given

```
public function rentalRate()
    {

$rate = implode("','",$this->rate);
$sql = "INSERT INTO rental(day_1,day_3,day_7,day_15,day_30)VALUES('$rate')";
$stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        unset($rate);
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't the rental table have a primary key?

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen yes it does

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `implode` and that's it

```
$rate = [10,20,40,50,70];
$rate = implode("','",$rate);
$sql = "INSERT INTO rental(day_1,day_3,day_7,day_15,day_30)VALUES('$rate')";
echo $sql;
```

Comment: If all is numeric, it would work. If you have a string, you have problems ;-)

Comment: What about this updated answer @RichardReiber

Comment: @Thank you Uchicha..it worked!

Comment: @Uchiha, but I have a problem..After inserting one array of rate into the database, if I fill in the array with other data without refreshing the page, the previous data record gets inserted once again.ANy way to solve this?

Comment: If you are having non numeric values, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31159680/3113793) should help

Comment: You can unset your array after insertion

Comment: like this unset($rate);? doesn't help :(

Comment: Yes like that `unset($rate);` or `$rate = array();`

Comment: @Uchiha, thanks but I'm curious about one thing.. Even after I unset the array...the array gets inserted few number of times..Example..if first time I insert it inserts one row, if second time 2 rows and increases so forth..WHere does this remember what  number of times I insert and it gets disppear only when I refresh..I didn't use session though!

Comment: Are you still using it within `foreach` loop from where you were getting the values of `$rate`

Comment: Nope I didn't use foreach..just using implode..And I unset after query executed with the function

Comment: But where is your function and from where are you getting that value of `$rate`

Comment: I'm getting it from another page..the array is passed to the function ,so from the function I insert.          $rate=$data["rate"];                                                                                              
$car->rate = $rate;
$car->rentalRate();

Comment: This answer is the completely wrong way to go. The normal approach is using a seperate table for the array valies and joining them with a sql join. The tools are not geared for this and you lose the ability to query the array and a hole bunch of other problems.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen can you post your answer for further users who met with the same condition

Comment: @Esben Skov Pedersen, this answer worked for me just as how I wanted it, just that I've no idea on how to disable whatever thingie that j=keeps track of the number of time I insert into the database.

Comment: @Vani its always good to have optimal solution if EsbenSkovPedersen have better answer than surely it'll be a good for you and for future users too

Answer (score 0):

Foreach is not useful in this case, because you want to integrate **more than one** array element in one query and you do not have a multidimensional array. Just use your first query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO rental(day_1,day_3,day_7,day_15,day_30)VALUES('{$rate[0]}','{$rate[1]}', '{$rate[2]}','{$rate[3]}','{$rate[4]}')";
```

And - if you really want to use foreach:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO rental(day_1,day_3,day_7,day_15,day_30)VALUES(";
foreach($rate as $value)
    $sql .= "'$value', ";
$sql = rtrim($sql, ", ") . ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

just simple (note implode will only work with integers, without need to quoate)

```
 $rate=[10,20,40,50,70];
 $r_sql = '';
 foreach($rate as $r) {
     $r_sql.="'$r',";
 }
 $r_sql = trim($r_sql,',');
 $sql="INSERT INTO rental(day_1,day_3,day_7,day_15,day_30)VALUES(".$r_sql.")";
```

Comment: See the answer of Uchiha, very nice solution for strings (Of course, the array should be walked through before to prevent SQL injections).

Answer (score 0):

Normally arrays are inserted into a different table and all tools are geared towards this. It is usually better not to fight the tools or it is likely to run into unforseen problems.

If we add a

```
table rental_day(id(int), rental_id(int,fk), rate(money))
```

Then for all the items in the array we just insert the item into one row in rental_day

later when we need the info back we can query for it like

```
select * from rental_day d inner join rental r on d.rental_id=r.id where r.id=something
```

and you will get all the info from rental_day and rental in one query.